# How can I download text from server?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, server

I need to download a JSON from server and deserialise it in my code to use it.

I know, that I need UnityWebRequest and a Coroutine. I understand two ways. 
I can StartCoroutine, send to the server a request and handle received data in that callee Coroutine, or
I can StartCoroutine, send a request and save the result to the class private variable. In that time, after StartCoroutine I can do while(variable == null), and after that handle data in caller method

```
private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(LoadPagesId("SomeURL.com"));
    }

    private IEnumerator LoadPagesId(string url)
    {
        var request = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
        yield return request.SendWebRequest();

        var data = request.downloadHandler.text;
        request.Dispose();

        // Do something with data
    }
```

OR

```
private string _str;

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(LoadPagesId("SomeURL.com"));
        while (_str == null)
        {

        }
        // Do something with data
    }

    private IEnumerator LoadPagesId(string url)
    {
        var request = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
        yield return request.SendWebRequest();

        _str = request.downloadHandler.text;
        request.Dispose();
    }
```

Is there some other way, without global variables and expanded LOAD methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can e.g. simply add callbacks:

```
private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(LoadPagesId("SomeURL.com"), HandleSuccess, HandleError);

    // Or as lambda expressions
    StartCoroutine(LoadPagesId("SomeURL.com"), success => {
       // do something with success
    }, error => {
       // do something with error
    });
}

private IEnumerator LoadPagesId(string url, Action<string> successCallback, Action<string> errorCallback)
{
    var request = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
    yield return request.SendWebRequest();

    if(www.error)
    {
        errorCallback?.Invoke(www.error);
    } 
    else
    {
        successCallback?.Invoke(request.downloadHandlet.text);
    }
}

private void HandleSuccess(string result)
{
    // Do something
}

private void HandleError(string error)
{
    // Do something
}
```